# could anyone explain me the sample script that i found on google

Tags: ajax

sorry but Im unable to understand these example. I started learning ajax right from today.

I have understood the below script so far

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
 {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
```

but in the below script

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 }
```

why do we use `document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText`. I dont understand why we are doing these.Could anyone kindly explain me these, Im not sure if the above script is optional or not, please let me know it.

and also the post method in Ajax

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname="+str);
```

what is the use of `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` Im unable to understand the parameters of it and why it is being used , what does it really do in the script. what do we mean by `content-type` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and its still working, even i dont give any user options

please help me with these both Then i believe I have completed the Ajax tutorials.Thanks

Comment: To understand what you're asking about AJAX, you really need to understand a bit about the HTTP protocol.  Including "response headers", "content types" and "HTTP status".  This link has some good information: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

This basically just set `textHint` with whatever result the AJAX has (`xmlhttp.responseText`).   And `textHint` could be simple html code with ID `textHint`:

```
<div id="textHint"></div>
```

That code is absolutely optional. You can do whatever process you want with the AJAX result, EG:

- alerting it: `alert(xmlhttp.responseText)`;
- do further process, maybe processing the XML (if it's XML document) or do JSON processing.
- Just anything you want.

For the next question:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname="+str);
```

is equal to sending HTML form:

```
<form method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="fname" value="{str}"/></form>
```

It try to send form data `fname` to server script `test.php` using `POST` method and transporting the data using MIME-TYPE `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. [You can read the full specification in W3 site](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's the core idea of the AJAX itself: update separate elements on the page without refreshing whole page. In your case you updating content fof the `txtHint` element.

This `document.getElementById("txtHint")` will return object of the control on the page.

This `document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` will set `innerHTML` property to the your response content.

Answer (score 1):

**part 1**

There you are initializing two objects, depending on type of browser. XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is a browser component in Mozilla, Safari, Chrome, Opera and Konqueror browser. And the ActiveXObject named "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" is also the same object but the object is an activeX in Microsoft Browser (Internet Explorer).

**Part 2**

xmlhttp .onreadystatechange is a property, in which you can write down your own business logic, for how to handle this XHR object once the request is sent.

xmlhttp.readyState is 1 when initialized, 2 when incomplete, 3 when about to complete and 4 when completed. xmlhttp.status is the HTTP status code (integer) for the request. common status are - 200 (OK), 303 (Moved), 404(not found) or 500 (internal server error).

So, if (xmlhttp.readyState == completed && xmlhttp.status = OK) { do something }

**part 3**

document.getElementById("someID") returns an HTML element in the document, by referring to it's ID. If the element is a text node, then DOM Element has a property called innerHTML which can be used to alter / append the content of the element.

**part 4**

xmlhttp.responseText - this is the response in plain text format, that is recieved from the server, to which you sent the request using the HTTP protocol.

There are other two format by which you can handle the server's response. They are,

xmlhttp.responseXML and xmlhttp.responseBody.

Hope this will help you in your ajax day 1. Yippee.